# Set Theory - Simplify expression

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can the following be simplified? It's been a long time since I did set theory and I don't remember my simplification rules. This is probably totally easy... can I simplify this any further?

$(A \cap B) \cap (A - B)$

Comment: Perhaps I've written it wrong?

I want (the intersection?) of everything in A and B, and also everything in A thats not in B

Comment: "and= $\cap$"....." or =$\cup$"

Comment: verything in A **and** B= $A\cap B$; **and** =$\cap$; everything in A thats not in B =$A-B$

Comment: So I think I'm correct in what I'm asking, just surprised everyone says this is empty? It relates to a programming problem... I need to list staff members who are in Team A or Team A and B, but not staff members who are in only Team B (staff can be in more than 1 team)

I wanted to find the simplest way.

Comment: I suggest you ask this comment as a new question. and be careful using **and-or**

Comment: just waiting to hit 20 minutes so I can post again :)

Comment: yes it seems that it is A; if the **or-and** parts are correct

Comment: @Regret Yes, but this is where me trying to oversimplify the issue makes it confusing... where I've said 'Team A', Team A is actually made up of about 8 teams. Do you follow? So programming in to include teams 1-8 (team A) and exclude those in JUST team 9 is possibly more effort in this case "give me team 1 AND team 2 AND team 3 AND ... etc." 

perhaps I should have just asked this as a coding question elsewhere... sorry keep rushing what im saying and needing to edit my nonsense

Comment: if anyone can think of a better way to phrase the question or communicate the problem that would help too!

Comment: this question is a mess, I've tried to explain way better here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292565/simplifying-set-theory-expression

I have a suspicion it might be I've used A and B instead of A or B somewhere now that I've thought about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(A \cap  B) \cap (A - B)= (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap B^c)=A \cap  B \cap B^c=\emptyset$

Comment: $B \cap B^c=\emptyset$

Comment: not what I was looking for but correct for my actual question I think, so accepted,

Answer (score 0):

For these things, it is the easiest way to make a picture. Then you immediately see that
$$ (A \cap B) \cap (A \backslash B) = \emptyset \; .$$
To proof this in a formal way, assume that there is a $x \in (A \cap B) \cap (A \backslash B)$. This would mean that $x \in A$, $x \in B$ and $x \not\in B$, which is obviously not possible.