# simplifying set theory expression

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to simplify a set theory expression, it relates to a programming problem... I have a set of staff members who are grouped into various teams (Team A, Team B, Team C etc ...up to Team H).

Each staff member can be in multiple teams (more often the case than not) and additional teams could be added in future.

I need to exclude the set of staff that are ONLY in Team A.

I think this could be expressed as:

$$
A \cap B^c \cap C^c \cap D^c \cap E^c \cap F^c \cap G^c \cap H^c
$$

Only I am required to express this as ***the set I am keeping***, as opposed to the set I am excluding, in the simplest way possible.

It's been a long time since I did set theory and I don't remember my simplification rules.

Is it not possible to express this in such a way that I can make:
$$
Z = (B \cap C \cap D \cap E \cap F \cap G \cap H)
$$

And then write the set I want to keep in terms of A and Z? It is programmatically possible for me to create the equivalent of Z for all future cases (even if new teams were to be added). By making Z = $A^c$.

$$
(A \cap Z) \cap (A \cap Z^c)
$$

When I program this in, I appear to get an empty set. What mistake have I made? Help appreciated!

I want to avoid expressing anything in an exhaustive list like:  (B ∪ C ∪ D ∪ E ∪ F ∪ G ∪ H) because this would break if a team 'I' were added (perhaps not possible?)

Comment: haha ok, I think I'm realising that no matter how well I word the question it not good enough... the issue with this is they could add extra teams in the future and I would have to update that to include e.g. Team I, Team J etc.

I want to avoid that if possible, its better for me to create the equivalent of Z for all future cases by just grouping the teams excluding A.

Sorry this is awkward! Still figuring out what I'm asking really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $B^c\cap C^c\cap\cdots\cap H^c=(B\cup C\cup\cdots\cup H)^c,$ so the set you're excluding is $$A\cap(B\cup C\cup D\cup E\cup F\cup G\cup H)^c.$$

So, if you let $Z$ be the *union* of all teams except team $A,$ then you have $A\cap Z^c=\left(A^c\cup Z\right)^c$ as the set you're excluding. The simplest expression for the set you're keeping, then, is $A^c\cup Z.$ Now, this assumes that it is possible for some of your people to be on *no teams at all*. If all are on at least one team, then we can instead just go with $Z$.

To see why the set you tried is empty, make a Venn diagram with two overlapping circles, labeled $A$ and $Z.$ Then $A\cap Z$ is the region contained in both circles, while $A\cap Z^c$ is the region contained in $A$ *only*. These regions do not intersect--that is, their intersection is empty.

Comment: All are in at least one team, but since they can be in more than 1 team, going with just Z pulls through the people who are e.g. Team A and Team B, I think?

Comment: As does $A^c \cup Z$

Comment: If all are in at least one team, then $A^c$ is a *subset* of $Z$, so $A^c\cup Z=Z.$

Comment: You are correct that $Z$ may contain some members of team $A$, but will include all who are members of team $A$ and at least one other team.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm being stupid here, I think $A^c \cup Z$ is actually what I want, I'm just being slow! I do want to include e.g. people in Team A and Team B

Thanks!

Comment: or Z in fact... wow